# Simple regex replaces more than it should in a string

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to create a regular expression that replaces an URL with a token. That's how far I got, and I don't understand why this expression replace everything after the URL as well except for the last word.

```
string<-"This is a website http://www.bla.com that I like very much"
gsub("https?://.*\\s|www.*\\s"," [url] ",string)

>>"this is a website  [url] much"
```

Appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `.*` - it will match *anything* greedily, so you will match all the way up to the *last* space. try 
`gsub("https?://[^[:blank:]]*","[url]",string)` instead.

Comment: oops, missed the closing `:`